# Create 10 lists and assign each 10 values in one loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variable-assignment

I have a DataFrame sized as 2 columns ; 'ID' and 'name'. And 100 rows (ID from 0 to 99). 
I want to create 10 groups as lists and put into each, 10 IDs. For example,

`group0 = (0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)`

`group2 = (2,12,22,32,42,52,62,72,82,92)`

...

is there a way to do it automatically ? I tried this :

```
var = 1
for i in range (0,10) :
    var = i
    "group{t}".format(t=var) = ()
    for j in range (0,10) :
        "group{k}".format(k=var).append(df.iloc[10*i+j][0])
```

but :

[image]

Comment: use a dictionary or an array inside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes it's possible to do it in automatically. 
As you have not included the complete code in your question, based on my understanding it should look something like below.

```
var =1
group = {} # Declare group object before assigning values
for i in range (0,10) :
    var = i
    group[var] = []  # Replace the brackets
    for j in range (0,10) :
        group[var].append(df.iloc[10*i+j][0])
```

The reason you are getting the error is due to using circular brackets instead.
Also, there is no need to add the format string in order to use a variable as an index if you use group like an object

Comment: is it possible with tuple ? (I wrote list but it is more tuple that I'm looking for)

Comment: It would be an issue with tuples since, tuples by nature are immutable and you won't be able to append values to it as in the case of a list. However, you can convert the list to a tuple as a second action 
group[var] = tuple(group[var]) after the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution to this which creates a list of lists

```
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(0,10):
    newList = []
    for j in range(0, 10):
        newList.append(i + j*10)
    list_of_lists.append(newList)
```

list_of_lists[0] = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
list_of_lists[1] = [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
...